# AngularJS Base Controller load module

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I have a baseController and a childController

Whenever I add modules to the baseController the app fails with the error:

```
Argument 'childController' is not a function, got undefined
```

EDIT: added a plnkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/mi9Ytv0HaqE47ENod4Gn

So this works:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('BaseController', baseController);

angular
    .module('app', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.pagination'])
    .controller('ChildController', childController)         

childController.$inject = ['$controller'];

function childController($controller) {
    var self = this;

    var baseController = $controller('BaseController', {
        $scope: self
    });
```

But this below does *not* work: (note the add of the 'ui.bootstrap' in the baseController module section....)

```
angular
    .module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller('BaseController', baseController);

angular
    .module('app', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.pagination'])
    .controller('ChildController', childController)         

childController.$inject = ['$controller'];

function childController($controller) {
    var self = this;

    var baseController = $controller('BaseController', {
        $scope: self
    });
```

Comment: I'm surprised the first example works. Are you sure?

Comment: Well, first thing to notice is that you're actually overriding `app` module. See [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module), section "Creation versus Retrieval"

Comment: Yes, I am sure the above first entry works = here is a plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/mi9Ytv0HaqE47ENod4Gn

Comment: I think  Ilya Luzyanin is somehow correct...  but I don't understand how I could get the inheritance i am looking for in this case...

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the `app` module twice. I'm not clever enough to determine what's happening, but it should probably look like this instead:

```
angular
    .module('app', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.pagination'])
    .controller('BaseController', baseController)
    .controller('ChildController', childController);
```

Answer (score 0):

For inheritance you can use standard JavaScript inheritance patterns. Here is a demo which uses $injector.

```
function Parent($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Human';
  $scope.clickParent = function() {
    $scope.name = 'Clicked from base controller';
  }    
}

function Child($scope, $injector) {
  $injector.invoke(Parent, this, {$scope: $scope});
  $scope.name = 'Human Child';
  $scope.clickChild = function(){
    $scope.clickParent();
  }       
}

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
```